# ProgressBar is not rotating - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

I am working on an Android Application , Here I am working with a **ProgressBar** , for which I am using `runOnUiThread()` to make **VISIBLE/GONE** from `doInBackground()` method of AsyncTask , I did not find other places except `doInBackground()` suitable to make VISIBLE/GONE ProgressBar to meet the UI requirement .

In this coding scenario ProgressBar is visible but not rotating , It is rotating when I make visible ProgressBar from `onCreate()` method of Activity .

I am not getting why it is happening , I visited few posts on Stackoveflow , they are saying that UI thread is not able to rotate ProgressBar since it is available in processing other tasks so as a fix I am not able to find other way to make it working .

So please help me what should be the fix of this issue .
Here is the code which I am using to make VISIBLE/GONE ProgressBar .

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
    int count;
    try {

        zipfileName = f_url[1];
        fUrl3 = f_url[2];

        if (fUrl3.equals("DontDownloadZip")) {
            return "DownloadSuccess";
        } else {
            Log.d("Downloading ", zipfileName);

            URL url = new URL(f_url[0]);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();

            // Hide ProgressBar after server connection .
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tipLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                }
            });

            // Code to download a file .
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream(),
                    8192);
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(MyBooks.screen
                    .getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/BookZips/"
                    + f_url[1]);
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            int counter = 0;

            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                counter++;
                total += count;

                // Display ProgressBar when percentage is 99 .
                if ((int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile) == 99) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if (!identifier1.equals("BookZips9Download"))
                                tipLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                }
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((total * 100) / lenghtOfFile));
                output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            android.os.FileUtils.setPermissions(MyBooks.screen
                    .getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/BookZips/"
                    + f_url[1], FileUtils.S_IRWXU | FileUtils.S_IRWXG
                    | FileUtils.S_IROTH | FileUtils.S_IWOTH
                    | FileUtils.S_IXOTH, -1, -1);

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "DownloadFailed";
    }

    return "DownloadSuccess";
}
```

Comment: You can visible it in onPreExecute() method of AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following line in your manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    >
```

Here, Replace ".MainActivity" to that activity where you used your async task code.

Comment: It will hold current information of your screen. Currently running process will not created again. Try it,may be help to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make the progress bar visible in **onPreExecute** method and hide your progress bar on **onPostExecute** method. this should resovle your problem as such you would not need to use runOnUIThread method

Comment: The scenario you told is the real scenario , idealy It should be , but it is not meeting UI requirements , Before this I tried the same you mentioned , I need to fix the issue in the coding scenario I attached .

Answer (score 0):

Do not put your UI code on doInBackground() (doInBackground() is executed on a background thread). This will crash because you are trying to access a UI thread's object (in this case, View object) in another thread.

If you want to update your progress bar:

1. In doInBackground(), trigger this method

> publishProgress(Integer... progress)

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
            // Do your background tasks
            publishProgress(progress);
    }
```

2. Override onProgressUpdate() method (You can safely access View objects here)

   ```
   protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
       // Updates your progress bar here
   }
   ```

Comment: Tried your way but I am getting same behaviour .